# Bachelier call option derivative w.r.t strike

Tags: options, derivatives, math

I tried to take the partial derivative of the Bachelier call function w.r.t. strike price K (eqn 2.2 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.1272.pdf#:%7E:text=Bachelier%2C%20as%20it%20is%20the,and%20needs%20no%20further%20explanation.)), but my result is not lining up with what is shown on page 43 [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/299490958_Option_Pricing_Model_comparing_Louis_Bachelier_with_Black-Scholes_Merton).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. the second source had a drift component in the SDE that i didnt have.